# Regex - Transforming url and get partial value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an url which I want to transform. I do it like this

JS:

```
var original_url;
var modified_url;

original_url = 'data/3458/3458-18-000003-index.html';
modified_url = original_url.replace( /(\d+-\d+-\d+-index.html)/, match => match.replace( /\D/g, '' ) + '/' + match.replace( '-index.html', '.txt' ) );

console.log(original_url);
console.log(modified_url);
```

And the result is:

Console:

```
/data/3458/3458-18-000003-index.html
/data/3458/345818000003/3458-18-000003.txt
```

Now in addition I want to get a partial value out of it. So the desired result should be:

Console:

```
/data/3458/3458-18-000003-index.html
/data/3458/345818000003/3458-18-000003.txt
345818000003
```

How can I get this additional value?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jh7195ao/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
var original_url;
var modified_url;
var add_value;

original_url = '/data/3458/3458-18-000003-index.html'; // '$2$3$4/$1.txt'
modified_url = original_url.replace(/((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+))-index\.html/, function ($0,$1,$2,$3,$4) {
  add_value = $2+$3+$4;
  return $2+$3+$4+'/'+$1+'.txt';
});

console.log(original_url); // /data/3458/3458-18-000003-index.html
console.log(modified_url); // /data/3458/345818000003/3458-18-000003.txt
console.log(add_value);    // 345818000003
```

Note I added more capturing groups to the pattern to have access to these parts later in the callback method:

- `((\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+))` - Group 1 (`$1`, to get rid of an additional replace later)

  - `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(\d+)` - Group 3 (`$3`): one or more digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(\d+)` - Group 4 (`$4`): one or more digits
- `-index\.html` - `-index.html` substring (note the escaped `.` to match a literal dot).